# Text area FielD display Sql value

Tags: php, sql

Im making a page to dit DB registers and i cant set the text area to display the value in db as the others :x I want it to display the DB value as all other so I can edit it.

My page

http://img.needforgaming.x10.mx/edit.php?NS24=24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
'<textarea>' . $sSomeText . '</textarea>'
```

Comment: Didnt work... what i wanna display is DB data like this : <?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Observacoes'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>

Comment: It didn't work, but you accepted it as the answer?

Comment: @TonySantos `<textarea><?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Observacoes'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?></textarea>` What's the problem?